# Finding out range in Java

Tags: java, csv, range

I'm trying to create a program as follows:

Given data from a csv/text file such as:

```
Colour, date, time, noise
red, 03/11/2014, 13:00, 10
blue, 04/11/2014, 14:00, 15
pink, 03/11/2014, 15:00, 50
blue, 05/11/2014, 14:00, 15
```

How do you return the range from 15:00 – 17:00 printing out the lines that are in the range and making sure the line that holds 17:00 is also returned

So if a user types in 03/11/2014 and 04/11/2014.. its will output:

```
red, 03/11/2014, 13:00, 10
blue, 04/11/2014, 14:00, 15
pink, 03/11/2014, 15:00, 50
```

This is my attempt:

```
package readFile;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class read {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    File fileName = new File("Data.csv");
    try {
        String startToken = "03/11/2014";
        String endToken = "04/11/2014";
        boolean output = false;

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(fileName);
        while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = scan.nextLine();
            if (!output && line.indexOf(startToken) >= -1) {
                output = true;
                line = line.substring(line.indexOf(startToken)+startToken.length());
            } else if (output && line.indexOf(endToken) > -1) {
                output = false;
                System.out.println(line.substring(0, line.indexOf(endToken)));
            }

            if (output) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

but the output is:

```
ate, time, noise
red, 03/11/2014, 13:00, 10
blue, 
, 15:00, 50
blue, 05/11/2014, 14:00, 15
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: You should probably use a table for this. Storing it in a CSV and sorting/filtering it likely has scaling limitations.

Comment: Convert the time values to int (ie 15:00 becomes 1500), they become easier to compare then...

Comment: Use `SimpleDateFormat` to convert the String into Date objects. After that comparations are way easier.

Answer (score 1):

You can use http://csvjdbc.sourceforge.net/ and use select query. Or import lines into some database directly ( in memory or true big db) - for cvs processing there are lot of libraries like opencsv and select values  via sql query.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example how you could implement it. The Java implementation tries to create Date objects from the given strings and compares them.

Input (Data.csv):

```
red, 03/11/2014, 13:00, 10
blue, 04/11/2014, 14:00, 15
pink, 03/11/2014, 15:00, 50
blue, 05/11/2014, 14:00, 15
```

Output:

```
Entry [colour=red, date=03/11/2014, time=13:00, noise=10]
Entry [colour=blue, date=04/11/2014, time=14:00, noise=15]
Entry [colour=pink, date=03/11/2014, time=15:00, noise=50]
```

Implementation:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RangeCalculator {
    private File file;
    public static final String DATE_FORMAT = "dd/MM/yyyy";

    public class Entry {
        String colour;
        String date;
        String time;
        String noise;

        public Entry(String colour, String date, String time, String noise) {
            super();
            this.colour = colour;
            this.date = date;
            this.time = time;
            this.noise = noise;
        }

        // implement getters and setters here if necessary

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Entry [colour=" + colour + ", date=" + date + ", time="
                    + time + ", noise=" + noise + "]";
        }
    }

    public RangeCalculator(String fileName) {
        file = new File(fileName);
    }

    private List<Entry> computeRange(String from, String to)
            throws FileNotFoundException, ParseException {

        List<Entry> result = new LinkedList<>();

        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT);
        Date fromDate = formatter.parse(from);
        Date toDate = formatter.parse(to);

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
        scanner.useDelimiter("[,\n]");

        // maybe you want/need to skip the first line of the file
        // if (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        //     scanner.nextLine();
        // }

        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {         
            String color = scanner.next();
            String date = scanner.next().substring(1);
            String time = scanner.next().substring(1);
            String noise = scanner.next().substring(1);

            Date currDate = formatter.parse(date);
            if (!currDate.before(fromDate) && !currDate.after(toDate)) {
                result.add(new Entry(color, date, time, noise));
            }
        }

        scanner.close();
        return result;
    }

    private void printEntries(List<Entry> entries) {
        for (Entry entry : entries) {
            System.out.println(entry.toString());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RangeCalculator app = new RangeCalculator("Data.csv");

        List<Entry> calculatedEntries = null;
        try {
            calculatedEntries = app.computeRange("03/11/2014", "04/11/2014");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.err.println("ERROR: File not found!");
            System.exit(1);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            System.err.println("ERROR: Wrong date format!");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        app.printEntries(calculatedEntries);
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```